# Angular 8 --base-href not working since upgrade

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been running this code with Angular 4 no problem:

```
 yarn sh-e2e --base-href='https://my-app.com'
```

sh-e2e is just configuring my settings for protractor testings. However, since I upgraded to Angular 8, I now keep seeing this error: **Unknown option: '--base-href'**

Most solutions I am seeing, are asking users to set the configurations  in their Angular.json file, but I need to be able to set mine dynamically through the CLI. I am basically changing the `--base-href` based on which environment I am currently deploying in, and another variable.

I've been searching but can't seem to find how to reference the `--base-href` dynamically, without just setting something in the configuration file (which doesn't fix my problem). I need a command to allow me to set the testing url dynamically. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<project_name>/`, maybe your format is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yarn sh-e2e --base-url='https://my-app.com'
```

Referencing it with --base-url instead of --base-href works with Angular 8!